# Signalr cross-domain connection user authentication

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm hosting my signalr hub on a separate domain and making cross domain connection to hub from my main application. When a user login into main application, signalr connection is established. Now, the problem I'm having is how to identify the connected user inside hub. If my HUb was within the main application then I could use the UserContext of the logged in user and maintain a dictionary (example from MessengR app) and update them on Connect and Disconnect event.

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _userConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _reverseLookup = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
```

But being a cross-domain connection, I don't have the UserContext and no way for me to know to whom that connection ID belongs to. I'm lost here. Is it possible to pass a query string from client on Connect() event? I have a token to identify a user which I can use to keep track. OR some other way to link the user to connection ID. If someone could give me some direction. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question...did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Nope, I moved to NodeJS and socket.io long back. I don't know if anything changed in signalr

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR cross-domain connection - connecting connection Id's with users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144002/signalr-cross-domain-connection-connecting-connection-ids-with-users)